# EDI and shipping tracking information

Tags: edi

I am new to EDI. I need to parse shipping / tracking information in my application. Which Transaction can I take as an example / sample files.

Comment: Ask the trading partner??

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have trading partners yet, it is a Proof of Concept

Comment: Well, you should probably look at a translator, unless you want to reinvent a 40 year old wheel.  Google 856 Advance Ship Notice.  That EDI document will give you shipping / tracking information.  Your question is kind of broad.

Comment: UN/EDIFACT or ASC X12? The example you've posted is X12. There's more than one standard for EDI, and aside from those two there's also XML-based formats such as UBL. Your question needs more specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different EDI files that could not be parsed using EDIFabric, I am posting an example:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*123123123      *ZZ*788082092LVS   *070226*1854*U*00204*000001535*0*P*:`
GS*SH*123123123*062442561*070226*1854*1535001*X*002040`
ST*856*1845`
BSN*00*00135043*070226*1852`
DTM*011*070226*1852*ET`
HL*1**S`
MEA*PD*G*3403*LB`
MEA*PD*N*3064*LB`
TD1*SKID *8`
TD5*B*2*HOZN*M`
TD3*TL**4824`
REF*BM*00135043`
REF*PK*00135043`
N1*SF**92*00912345`
N1*ST**92*0999`
N1*SU**92*00900005`
REF*DK*C`
HL*2*1*I`
LIN**BP*8765432-1234`
SN1**1758*PC*791262`
PRF*123456`
CLD*6*293*SKID `
CTT*2`
SE*22*1845`
GE*1*1535001`
IEA*1*000001535`
```

Comment: Where did you put the actual tracking number? And where do you specify if it was UPS, FEDEX, USPS etc...?